# excel one to many look up

Tags: excel, one-to-many, lookup

I would like to use a lookup formula to bring back multiple values. For example when it finds more than value in a look up I would like excel to add each value in the adjacent columns.

Can anyone help?

see attached

[image]

Comment: I think you want SUMIF().

Comment: no, like for example, a vlookup, but there are multiple rows with the lookup value in the table, I would like for it create a new column for each of the value

Comment: Maybe some test data and expected outcome will help.  Please post some in your original post using edit.

Comment: added a picture...thank you for your help

Comment: One comment:  going back through your history, I am not sure you are aware that only you can mark an answer as correct.  This is done by clicking the check mark by the answer that you ended up using.  I see that you have not marked any of your questions with a correct answer.  Over time people may not be willing to help if there is never any feed back.  It also helps future readers know which one worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$13,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$13=$H$2)*(COUNTIF($H$2:H$2,$B$2:$B$13)=0),0)),"")
```

Being an array formula, put it in the first cell then hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Then copy/drag across enough columns till you get blanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this formula :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$13,SMALL(IF($H2=$A$2:$A$13,ROW($A$2:$A$13)-ROW($A$2)+1),COLUMN(A2))),"")
```

As this is also an array formula, press Ctrl+Shift+Enter while entering the formula.[image]